# Progress carousel forward or backward if button click else timed progress forward

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a manual and automatic scrolling slideshow. I'm having trouble getting the carousel to progresses to the next slide when the left facing arrow is clicked and to move backwards through the slide when the right facing arrow is clicked, while maintain the 5 second automatic progression to the next side.

```js
window.onload = function() { // add window.onload here and set it euqal to a function
  var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  
  // Next/previous controls
  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }
  // Thumbnail image controls
  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) 
   {
     slideIndex = 1
   }   
    if (n > slides.length) {
   slideIndex = 0
   } 
    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
  }
  
  
 }
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
*/
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<html>

  <!-- Slideshow container -->
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997100823773184/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >one on one weekly siminars</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997228791988244/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >monthly seminars/workshops</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997338716176395/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >nursing home visits</span></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="pictures%20updated/42.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >community service</span></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="pictures%20updated/21.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >college visits</span></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  

  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="curretnslide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentslide(5)"></span>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, i fixed your problem. Added function `bind` that will reset the timeinterval.

And also fixed the arrows

```js
window.onload = function() { // add window.onload here and set it euqal to a function
   var timeOut;
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var slides;
   showSlides(slideIndex);
  // Next/previous controls
  window.plusSlides =function (n) {
     showSlides(n);
  }
  // Thumbnail image controls
  window.currentSlide = function(n) {
       slideIndex = (n -1)
      showSlides();
  }
    
    function bind(){
     clearInterval(timeOut)
     timeOut =setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
    }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
      if (n)
      slideIndex += n;
       else slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex >= slides.length || slideIndex < 1) 
   {
     slideIndex = 1
   }  
    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex -1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex -1].className += " active";
     bind();
  }
    

  
  
 }
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 42px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  z-index:999999;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
*/
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
 <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997100823773184/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >one on one weekly siminars</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997228791988244/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >monthly seminars/workshops</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997338716176395/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >nursing home visits</span></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="pictures%20updated/42.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >community service</span></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="pictures%20updated/21.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
   <div class="text"><span style = "background-color: black" >college visits</span></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  

  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: I get the gist of what your saying but the arrow keys don't work. I did notice I might have forgotten a arrow for the right side. sorry about that

Comment: Nothing was working at first so i hade to fix the dots and also the timer problem, and now updated my answer and also fixed the arrow issue you hade

Answer (score 1):

It's still a bit buggy but is this what you want?

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}
// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
*/
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997100823773184/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">one on one weekly siminars</span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997228791988244/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">monthly seminars/workshops</span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502541850985496596/536997338716176395/image0.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">nursing home visits</span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="pictures%20updated/42.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">community service</span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="pictures%20updated/21.jpg" style="width:970px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">college visits</span></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some what, yes. I had it that far but trying something different and broke it. but yes that's somewhat i'm going for.